# Tag creation request in hardware recommendations

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like to add the tags, open-hardware, and open-source, for product descriptions, related to the hardware having an open design, such as available schematics, and or pcb layouts, and for hardware that is programmable using open-source code, or available commands. Due to inadequate reputation, I cannot create these topic tags inside the [hardware recommendation site](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

I'm not sure if this belongs in meta.

Answer (score 3):

We don't just add tags unless there's a question that requires them.

If you want to include these tags on a question you ask, leave a comment under the question asking someone with enough reputation to add the tags for you.

If you've found an existing question you want to add the tags to, drop me a link in a comment under this post, and I'll add the tag.